# How to log in to a postfix+dovecot mail account

Tags: postfix, dovecot

After roughly 6 hours of searching i decided to ask help here

I've tryied setting up postfix, everything worked great

Then I've decided to use my emails on thunderbolt, which didn't work

So i figured out that i had to setup a SASL auth, so I did (Or at least, i think I've set it up as telnet replies with "AUTH PLAIN")

Okay, now that you have a general idea, there are my configs:

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/randomdevs.org/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/randomdevs.org/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
myhostname = randomdevs.org
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $mydomain, $myhostname, localhost.$myhostname, , localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mydomain = randomdevs.org
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
virtual_alias_domains = $mydomain
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

/etc/postfix/master.cf

```
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -v

pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp -v
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
        
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd

maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRXhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
  
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
  
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FRX user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
```

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf

```
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
!include auth-system.conf.ext
```

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf

```
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 110
  }
}

service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }
}
```

Telnet output

```
Trying 207.180.254.22...
Connected to randomdevs.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 randomdevs.org ESMTP Postfix
EHLO $hostname
250-randomdevs.org
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250-SMTPUTF8
250 CHUNKING
AUTH PLAIN
334
xxxxxxxx **HERE, I'VE USED A BASE64 STRING ENCODED LIKE SO: echo -ne "\000username\000password" | openssl base64
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
root **IM NOT SURE HERE IF IT IS THE RIGHT THING TO WRITE, IN FACT, I DON'T KNOW**
```

As you can see, I'm unable to login.

How is this possible? Could someone help me or anything?

Thanks in advance, and have a nice day!

EDIT:
I've edited the Telnet output to explain better what i did, and when I'm talking about thunderbird, "Didn't work" means this:
[Thunderbird settings][1]
[Used user][2]

*P.S: Please don't downvote this question, I've really searched everything that I could, and after 6/7 hours I gave up and tryied to ask here. Be nice please, this is the first time I've ever used postfix*

With those settings, thunderbird still says that it can't find the settings for my email account.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra92L.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM4kX.png

Comment: Dovecot [ships a command specifically to test your dovecot authentication](https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/debugging/debugging_authentication/#debugging-authentication): `doveadm auth test user` - have you tried that? What does it say?

Comment: Hello @anx, thanks for your answer, this helped a bit with the understanding of the problem, doveadm auth test test 1234 DOES work. 


passdb: info auth succeeded

and also, i'm editing the question

Answer (score 1):

On wire LOGIN credentials are presented not in the raw form, but base64-encoded, just like it presented words "Username" and "Password" to you. So, for example, username `root` will be sent as `cm9vdA==`.

The PLAIN auth uses both username and password serialized into a single string, which is again base64-encoded: `base64('\0' | login | '\0' | password)`, where `|` denotes concatenation and `'\0'` is a literal zero octet (an ASCII NUL character). The string encoded this way is replied after `334` message, or put directly into auth command. There could be additional thing before first NUL, but don't care about that yet, if you do, read [RFC4616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4616.txt).

Read for example, [here](https://www.samlogic.net/articles/smtp-commands-reference-auth.htm) for details.

A word of caution: **never enable LOGIN or PLAIN mechanism without SSL/TLS layer**, because anybody who can capture traffic can observe these base64 strings on the wire, decode them and extract credentials.

Comment: Hello Nikita, thanks! This is probably the problem.
But how should I encode the string? I've edited the question (See telnet output) and as you can see, I've did this, what i'm doing wrong?